# What does it mean to be the left operand?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to figure out why this code works (particularly the "price" part)

```
struct CarType
{
    string maker;
    int year;
    float price;
    bool operator > (carType car)
    {
        if (price > car.price)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
};
```

It says "we don't nees a myCar.price, because myCar was the left operand". What does that mean? I wrote this in another .h file:

```
bool operator > (Fraction a, Fraction b)
{
    if (a.numerator*b.denominator > b.numerator*a.denominator) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

See how I passed 2 Fraction structs? I'm not sure why the "myCar" only has to pass one CarType data struct or what the explanation means. Can someone please enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CarType` is a struct.  It contains information about a car.  Assuming it has been initialized properly, it has set values for `maker`, `year`, and `price`.

`bool operator > (carType car)` is a member operator of `CarType`.  When the member operator `>` is called, it is called from/by the object on the left, just like a function would be.  If you had a function inside `CarType` called `myFunction`, you would call it like this:

```
myCar.myFunction();
```

And it would operate on the data already set up inside `myCar`, right?  It's the same with operators.  When you create the `>` operator for `CarType`, you call it like this:

```
myCar > otherCar
```

Probably with an if or something surrounding it, but the point stands.  Since `myCar` is on the left of the `>` operator, it is the left operand.  `>` is called on `myCar`, and `otherCar` is passed in as the right hand variable.  The operators just make things look prettier; in this case, your `>` function is the same as if you'd written this function inside `CarType`:

```
bool isGreaterThan (carType car)
{
    if (price > car.price)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

And then this function would be called like this:

```
myCar.isGreaterThan(otherCar);
```

In this case it's clear what's going on, right?  `myCar` is the object the function is being called on; `otherCar` is the car it's being compared against.  It's similar when you use the operator; it's implied that the left operand is calling the function, and the right operand is passed in.  Overloading operators makes code simple and easy to read, and provides flexibility (ie. there are some data structures which would now perform sorts based on your `>` operator, which they couldn't do if you decided to define equality with an `isGreaterThan` function.

I hope this clears up your confusion; please let me know if there's anything else you'd like me to explain!

Answer (score 2):

If you write `operator>` as a free function (not a member of the class) then you need two operands.

If you write it as a member function, then you still have two operands, but one of them is the hidden `this` operand. (Remember that when you call a non-static member function, you are calling it on a specific instance of the class.)

It might help you to understand if I put in the implicit `this->`

```
bool operator > (carType car)
{
    if (this->price > car.price)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

It also means you can compare cars like this if you want:

```
CarType one, two;
if (one.operator>(two)) // same as if (one > two)
{
    // some code...
}
```

Comment: I think the use of the explicit `operator>` makes this clearer, good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Three points:

1. Passing the parameter(s) by value is expensive, because all the data members have to be copied.
2. Since the comparison does not alter the objects, you should sprinkle `const` on your code.
3. `if (expr) return true; else return false;` can always be simplified to `return expr;`

Modified code:

```
bool operator>(const carType& car) const
{
    return price > car.price;
}

bool operator>(const Fraction& a, const Fraction& b)
{
    return a.numerator*b.denominator > b.numerator*a.denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `operator>` is a member of `CarType`, so the instance of `CarType` that calls it is the left operand. The second `operator>` is not a member of anything, so the left operand must be specified.